# Spilt value from a column in a DataFrame using Python

Tags: python, numpy, python-2.7, dataframe, pandas

I have a data frame with 4 columns..

```
A    B     C      D
e    2     =     <0.1
e    2     =     <0.11
e    2     =      0.1
e    2     =      0.1
e    2     =      0.1
e    2     =     <0.14
```

Column D has some float values starting with '<' and some are without '<'.

For the rows which have '<' in front I want to cut that and move into column C before the '=' sign.

How do I do it?

If I use normal slice it will cut values where there is no '<' sign.

And `startswith` does not work on float values.

Comment: If you want to use `startswith` with a float, you can just first convert it to a str with str(). But I do not really see how the column D can be of type float?

Comment: @joris column D is of type `'object'` (so it can have both strings and floats).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it, if I understand you correctly. This is very quick and dirty, untested. Reads the named file, prints to stdout:

```
for l in open("file.txt").readlines():
  l = l.strip()
  fields = l.split(" ")
  if len(fields) != 4: continue
  if fields[3][0] == "<":
    fields[2] = "<"
    fields[3] = fields[3][1:]
  print "\t".join(fields)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function which takes an entry in `df.D` columns and returns a Series. Then you can use Series [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) with this function:

```
def f(d):
    try:
        if d[0] == '<':
            return pd.Series(['<=', float(d[1:])])
    except TypeError:
        return pd.Series(['==', d])

In [9]: df = DataFrame({'A': {0: 'e', 1: 'e', 2: 'e', 3: 'e', 4: 'e', 5: 'e'}, 'B': {0: 2, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 2}, 'C': {0: '=', 1: '=', 2: '=', 3: '=', 4: '=', 5: '='}, 'D': {0: '<0.1', 1: '<0.11', 2: 0.1, 3: 0.1, 4: 0.1, 5: '<0.14'}})

In [10]: df
Out[10]: 
   A  B  C      D
0  e  2  =   <0.1
1  e  2  =  <0.11
2  e  2  =    0.1
3  e  2  =    0.1
4  e  2  =    0.1
5  e  2  =  <0.14

In [11]: df[['C', 'D']] = df.D.apply(f)

In [12]: df
Out[12]: 
   A  B   C     D
0  e  2  <=   0.1
1  e  2  <=  0.11
2  e  2  ==   0.1
3  e  2  ==   0.1
4  e  2  ==   0.1
5  e  2  <=  0.14
```

Comment: @Rahul Aha! I've just realised why my previous code wasn't working, it was my DataFrame being different to yours (all strings) in my example. Give me a couple of min.

Comment: @RahulBhatia It's funny because this was what was in my first version of my answer! This explains my previous "surprise"!

Comment: My column D is of object type not string...when I run ur code the compiler just freaks out

Comment: @ Hayden - your code is working bcoz you are using column D as a string...for me it's an Object type

Comment: @RahulBhatia when I updated last time I changed the dataframe to object (some strings and some floats), previously it had been all strings having been read in by read_csv. The above `df` (with D an object) and `f` work as described for me...